# How to find creation date of databricks interactive cluster?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, azure-powershell, azure-cli, databricks-cli

Is there a way to know creation date of databricks interactive cluster ?

I looked at configuration tab as well as JSON of ARM but couldn't find it..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Cluster event logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/clusters-manage#event-log), which capture cluster lifecycle events, like creation, termination, configuration edits, and so on.

The cluster event log displays important cluster lifecycle events that are triggered manually by user actions or automatically by Azure Databricks. Such events affect the operation of a cluster as a whole and the jobs running in the cluster.

[image]